# How to autosize path to grid container in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

In WPF application, text is going out of its path as per screenshot.Please suggest how can we autosize it according to resolution/window size.i tried to set few property but did not help.

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="0" >
        <Popup x:Name="popLines"   
           PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=btn}"
           Placement="Relative" 
           IsOpen="False"
           Width="750"
           ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"          
           AllowsTransparency="True"
           StaysOpen="False"
           PopupAnimation="Scroll"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           VerticalAlignment="Top"
           HorizontalOffset="-190" VerticalOffset="0"
           ToolTip="Approval Screen Help">

            <Grid Margin="10">
                <Path Fill="LightBlue" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="LightBlue" 
                StrokeThickness="3" StrokeLineJoin="Round"
                Margin="0" Data="M130,154 L427.5,154 427.5,240.5 299.5,240.5 287.5,245.5 275.5,240.5 130,240.5 z">
                    <Path.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="12" Color="Black" Direction="315" Opacity="0.8"/>
                    </Path.Effect>
                </Path>

                <Grid Margin="10,5,10,5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource XBtn}" Click="btn1_Click" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                Text="{Binding ApprovalScreenHelp}"> 

                    </TextBlock>

                </Grid>


            </Grid>
        </Popup>

    </Grid>
```

[image: below is the output of above code]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. But you can user a `ViewBox` to change the size according to screen resolution. You can read about `ViewBox` here https://wpftutorial.net/ViewBox.html

Comment: my question is related to autosize of this blue box as per resolution change.if you see,text is overflowing from the container which needs to be fixed.i hope its more clear now

Comment: Is your text always same length?

Comment: yes its loading from a xml

Comment: You could wrap you text into WrapPanel, then wrappanel into viewbox, and then set viewbox width/height as path width/hight

Comment: cant we do anything in the existing code?

Comment: but i would just use scrollViewer and made text scrollable

Comment: use viewbox over textblock

Comment: @sTrenat - i tried wrapping textblock inside viewbox,i cant see any text in that case.and also tried to replace textblock with viewbox but how can we bind text to viewbox like we do in textblock using                 Text="{Binding ApprovalScreenHelp}".i am new to WPF so asking such basic question.

Comment: i have changed code  like below                                             
              <Viewbox x:Name="canvasHelper" Grid.Row="1" Stretch="Fill">
                       <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
     Text="{Binding ApprovalScreenHelp}"> 
                                                </TextBlock>
                        </Viewbox>
problem now is font size of text which became smaller which is not readable.how can we adjust font size like before

Comment: any idea how to fix font size when using textblock inside viewbox??